# Two Questions Concerning Standard Buttons on Search Layout Recently Viewed List (i.e. Add To Campaign)

Tags: list-view, button, search-layout

I am working for a client using a test org (The client also has a Stage and a Production Org).
I need to add the *Add To Campaign* button to the Recently Viewed List in Test org and Stage org.
I noticed that the Production org has this button displayed for its Recently Viewed List of leads.
However on both the Test and Stage orgs list of leads, when I used the following series of commands I saw that the Lead Search Layout's *List View* layout did not exist. Here is the command sequence I used:

```
Set up> Lead> Search Layout> look for "List view"> Edit it and Check the *Add To Campaign* option.
```

Q) What happened to the *List View* for the Test and Stage orgs for the Lead Search Layout?

Q) Is the List View layout only for Salesforce Classic? I had always thought that there was a lightning version also.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have administrative permissions? As far as I can tell, they should always be there in any edition that supports leads.

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess that might be the case although our client has set my company up to have a Salesforce System Admin profile for the first account and for the second account we have the Marketing profile (For testing purposes) . I had forgotten that there are ways to take away permissions from a System Admin profile for a consultant user.

Comment: If you have the Marketing profile, you also need to have the Marketing User checkbox enabled on your user detail page to access campaigns. That's probably why you don't have the button.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks I will check that in my dev org and let you know.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yep thanks!! That's exactly what it was. I also know how to hide the Add To Campaign buttons in the Campaign History related lists for both contacts and leads because  our client wants those removed .

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

My Thanks goes to @sfdcfox  who was able to solve this issue.  This resolution is tricky to locate within the SF Help documents depending on how you search and if you know a bit about User record fields. Otherwise, you would be thinking that the solution comes from the Search Layout (as it does for Classic) . His suggested fix was:
I needed to have the *Marketing User* checkbox enabled on my User record detail page in order to display the Add To Campaign button. That's  why the button was not displayed. Simple and quick.